# Mapping CAPS to ESC for Vim on Ubuntu?

Tags: vim, remapping

I have been trying to figure it out using others' posts for a while and I can't figure it out. I tried setxkbmap but it doesn't stay when I reboot. The settings > keyboard > manual shortcut entry route didn't work either. Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to avoid pressing the ESC key, or does it not work?

Comment: Yes I find that I always press F1 by mistake when trying to hit ESC and then I have to wait for this stupid window to load before I can exit out of it.

Comment: You can also use Ctrl+[ to do the same thing.  Try getting into the practice of that maybe.